# Диспетчеризация собственных событий. Как объект сообщает о своем состоянии родителю в java?

Tags: java, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования, события

Вопрос **#1: Каким образом в java объект может сообщить об изменении какой либо переменной своему родителю?**

Я так понимаю, что для этого используются *диспетчеризация событий*? Только так, или есть еще какие то варианты?

> Почему спрашиваю, потому что на счет кастомных событий ничего толком
>   не нашел, и думаю может в java все иначе, чем в AS3. Очень странно,
>   что на эту тему информации почти нету.

Нашел следующий вариант, как диспатчить в java:

```
//определяем функциональный интерфейс:

package sample;
public interface EventListener {
    void dispatch(String s);
}
```

в родительском классе:

```
    // прописываем лямбда выражение

    EventListener listener = e -> {
        if (e.equals(snake.CHANGE_IS_LIVE)) // будем проверять типы событий
            System.out.println("new event: " + e); // логика ...
    };

    snake.setListener(listener); // устанавливаем слушатель на дочерний объект
```

дочерний объект:

```
    // на пока просто константы, можно сделать перечисление ENUM (типы событий)
    String CHANGE_IS_LIVE = "[change is live]";
    String CHANGE_IS_MOVE = "[change is move]";

    private EventListener listener; // ссылка на обработчик

    public void setListener(EventListener l) { 
        this.listener = l;
    }

    public void dispatch() {
        listener.dispatch(CHANGE_IS_LIVE); // собственно создаем событие <-
    }
```

В принципе работает, но выглядит не очень. **Второй #2 Правильно ли использовать данную реализацию?** Или же есть варианты по проще, и более правильные? И как поступали раньше до появления лямбда выражений (до java8)?

**Вопрос #3 Почему так мало информации на этот счет, неужели данная задача не актуальна?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если без блокировки основного потока, то есть 2 варианта для этого:

1. Как у тебя в примере - через передачу лисенера/коллбека;
2. Через `CompletableFuture`:

   ```
   import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

   public class FutureDispatching
   {
       volatile int val;

       public void doTask()
       {
          CompletableFuture.supplyAsync( () ->
           {
               try {
                   Thread.sleep(3000);
               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               return 42;
           }).whenComplete((v, b) -> doSmth(v));

           System.out.println("Main thread do it's job concurently to the future");

           // do some more task when future continues to execute...
       }

   private void doSmth(int val)
   {
       this.val = val;
       System.out.println("doSmth");
       // something more...
   }


   public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {
       new FutureDispatching().doTask();

       Thread.sleep(10000);

       System.out.println("Main thread has ended");

     }
   }
   ```